# Hibernate deatched entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, orm

I'm getting this PersistanceObjectException being thrown during one of my integration tests.

The the test it self runs fine when run on its own, but not as part as a test suite. So I added DirtiesContext to all the integration tests, however this for some reason has had no affect.

I've confirmed that the entity I'm trying to persist DOES NOT exist, when I try to persist it. However, the error only occurs when a previous test (in a different class) does the same persist.

If this was a case of the entity staying persisted from one case to the next, why isn't DirtiesContext would fix this, and my check to see if the entity is already persisted would be true.

The persist operation is a simple entityManager.persist(entity). Nothing complex or fancy.

Any ideas? I'm really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you set up the integration testing database. The DirtyContext setting will only recreate the Spring application context, so unless you have a Spring context life-cycle aware in-memory database, the DB might not get cleaned-up between test runs.

In your case, the entity you provide simply has the id set. If you don't supply a newly created entity, the persist operation will fail.

So, make sure the entity id is null when you pass it to persist.

Comment: You're right, the entity being persisted does have it's id set, however if I try to get that entity using a DAO I get null back. This is what confuses me, only by stopping at a break point can I see that the entity created has an id before being persisted, yet every thing I do before then suggests that the entity doesn't exist.

Comment: Try using merge instead of persist, and call flush() afterwards.

Comment: Persist is the correct call here. I've narrowed down the issue and may need to ask a different question. DirtiesContext is not working as it should. 
A particular bean I have populates a list, at the beginning of the second test, this bean's list is populated with the data from the last run. 
As this list contains new entities to persist, at the end of the second test it will have two copies of each entity, hence causing the error.